# Does alternating silicone sheets with silicone gel yield a better scar reduction than using silicone sheets or silicone gel alone?

Tags: dermatology, surgery, wound-care, sutures, cosmesis

ScarAway's packaging mentions (ScarAway is one of the main brands for silicone gels and silicone sheets in the United States):

> For best results: Use as part of a complete scar treatment regimen, alternating use [of silicone get] with ScarAway Silicone Scar Sheets.

[image]

However no evidence is given of the usefulness of alternating Scar Sheets with gel and obviously, there could be a financial bias.